# How to escape special chars in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I am using pattern-matching in `OCaml` to check for valid chars in a string and if the `\0` is passed to the pattern-matching function it will print a message to the screen that the end of the string was found.

```
let my_fun char = 
    match char with
      'a' .. 'z' -> Printf.printf ("Valid ALPHA found: %c\n") char;
    | 'A' .. 'Z' -> Printf.printf ("Valid ALPHA found: %c\n") char;
    | ' ' -> Printf.printf ("WHITE_SPACE found\n");
    | '\0' -> Printf.printf("End of string reached\n"); (* The backslash isn't escaped *)
    | _ -> Printf.printf ("Invalid Token found\n"); 
 ;;
```

The compiler is giving the Error:

```
 Error: Illegal backslash escape in string or character (\0)
```

How do you escape the `\` or check if the null terminater/line feed was passed in to `my_fun` in `OCaml`?

Comment: Next time, reading the [ocaml documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/) would be faster than asking here (read about [character literals](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html) there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Char.chr(0)` instead, or simply `'\000'`.

-- fix -- 
Char.chr(0) indeed does not work - I suppose this is because it is not considered as a constant.

'\000' does work.

```
let my_fun char = 
    match char with
      'a' .. 'z' -> Printf.printf ("Valid ALPHA found: %c\n") char;
    | 'A' .. 'Z' -> Printf.printf ("Valid ALPHA found: %c\n") char;
    | ' ' -> Printf.printf ("WHITE_SPACE found\n");
    | '\000' -> Printf.printf("End of string reached\n"); (* The backslash isn't escaped *)
    | _ -> Printf.printf ("Invalid Token found\n"); 
 ;;
let a = Char.chr(0);;
my_fun a;;
```

Will provide :

```
utop # my_fun a;;
End of string reached
- : unit = ()
```

Comment: When I use the `'\000'` the program compiles but it doesn't match with the `'\0'` and using the `Char.chr(0) -> Printf.printf("End of string reached\n");` gives a syntax error. Is there a way to use something like `| (int_of_char char) = 10 -> Printf.printf("End of string reached\n");`

Comment: Thank you for the response @Pierre G. your answer does answer the question of how to escape the \ in the code I provided. After further evaluating your answer and seeing you where using ascii value 0 and my comment of `(int_of_char char) = 10`. I had forgot that the null character `'\0'` and the newline character `'\n'` are two different character values, just as `'x'` and `'y'` are two different character values. Fixed my issue with `| '\n' -> Printf.printf("Ending of string reached\n");`